# Can I receive notifications about new IP addresses connected to my server?

Tags: linux, open-source, python, django, nginx

I have a django website deployed on AWS EC2 behind Nginx, without wsgi right now (I'm still in the early stage of development and checking my options).
I've noticed in my nginx access log a few new IP addresses, that are not mine.

Is there any tool available to send notifications about new connections?

I can develop a script for that, but maybe there is a tool already within some wsgi, Nginx or even Django.

It doesn't really matter for me, if it can send e-mails or if it integrates with slack/telegram. Any type of notification would be great.